# Adding phtml file to static blocks in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magento. And while creating static block on my own in magento dashboard, it doesnt compile php code. So i need to call a phtml file But I am not sure what needs to be done for this. The code I need to put in static block is :

```
<div class="account-login">
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Login or Create an Account') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <div class="col2-set">
        <div class="col-1 new-users">
            <div class="content">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Customers') ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $this->__('By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more.') ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 registered-users">
            <div class="content">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Registered Customers') ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $this->__('If you have an account with us, please log in.') ?></p>
                <ul class="form-list">
                    <li>
                        <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="pass" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                </ul>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
                <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2-set">
        <div class="col-1 new-users">
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?>" class="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo Mage::helper('persistent')->getCreateAccountUrl($this->getCreateAccountUrl()) ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 registered-users">
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>
                <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('checkout')->isContextCheckout()): ?>
        <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create a custom template file in your theme and call that file i static block like

```
{{block type="core/template" template="templateFolder/your_template.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but sir the file I need to call is in persistent folder and if I move it to another folder it stops redirecting to next page...is there anyway that I can call a .phtml file from persistent folder.

Comment: you just need to change the templateFolder  to your folder name for ed  
if your folder name is persistent than it will be as
{{block type="core/template" template="persistent/your_template.phtml"}}